# Migrate Wordpress Entries From MS SQL to MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, wordpress

I have an old WordPress blog that was running with a MS SQL database backend.   The MS SQL database provider for WordPress is no longer supported.   We have setup a completely new install of WordPress and pointed it to a new MySQL database.   I need to migrate the blog entries from the old MS SQL database to the new MySQL database.   Is there an plugin to do it?   The only ones I have been are for migrating one MySQL database to another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to migrate is to not try and migrate the database tables themselves between MS and MySQL or export from phpmyadmin and transfer.

Try the WordPress Export function to export all your pages, posts, categories, etc., - or simply the blog posts and nothing else - into an XML file which can then can imported into a new WordPress install. See https://codex.wordpress.org/Tools_Export_Screen for details. It is a highly reliable way to transfer content from install to install, and it is smart enough to not duplicate posts if you run it multiple times to import a large file. When it is run, you'll get options to import images, map content to new or existing users, etc.

If your new site will have the same absolute URL path as the old - i.e. `example.com/wp-content/uploads...` - you may not even have to allow the importer to import images; just move the `wp-content/uploads/...` folder over to the new WordPress install.